# how to move a div when it's father wrap rotate 45 degree

Tags: javascript, web, mobile

[the sketch map is what I want to realize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GND7g.png)

I used javascript touchmove event to move a picture, it works when the picture wrapper without rotate, when I give the wrapper 45 degree, the picture movement is not correct, it will move relative to the wrapper, I want to make it move like the upper sketch map, thanks for reading my first question on stack overflow.

my simple code

```
html

<div class="wrap">
  <img v-for="item in imgs"
    @touchstart="WraptouchStart($event, item)"
    @touchmove="WraptouchMove($event, item)"
    @touchend="WraptouchEnd($event, item)"
  >
</div>

css
.wrap {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```
javascript

WraptouchStart(e, item) {
    item.lx = e.touches[0].clientX;
    item.ly = e.touches[0].clientY;
},
WraptouchMove(e, item) {
    item._lx = e.touches[0].clientX;
    item._ly = e.touches[0].clientY;

    item.left += (item._lx - item.lx);
    item.top += (item._ly - item.ly);
    item.x += (item._lx - item.lx);
    item.y += (item._ly - item.ly);
            
    item.lx = e.touches[0].clientX;
    item.ly = e.touches[0].clientY;
},
WraptouchEnd(e, item) {
    // do something     
},
```

Comment: What code did you write for that?

Comment: @A7x I update the description and the code